# How to extract "runtime" bin from a EVM bin found on etherscan.io

Tags: solidity, evm, etherscan, bytecode

I would like to extract the `runtime` bin from the EVM `bin` that can be found in the etherscan.io.

For instance for this famous contract (https://etherscan.io/address/0xecb4380189e22ed2abccff53a6ac1d1e02bd6981), when I use the online decompiler (https://ethervm.io/decompile?address=0xecb4380189e22ed2abccff53a6ac1d1e02bd6981&network=) to decompile, clearly it starts from a bytecode sequence `606060405236156100f8`, which is **not the very beginning** of this EVM bytecode sequence.

I understood that I can do a pattern match to figure out a sequence of `606060405236`, but I am a bit worried whether that's too "ad-hoc", and unable to handle all the cases. So could anyone shed some lights on a more principled approach here? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the bytecode of a contract you have to call [web3.eth.getCode](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetcode).

An example from the linked page

```
var code = web3.eth.getCode("0xd5677cf67b5aa051bb40496e68ad359eb97cfbf8");
console.log(code); // "0x600160008035811a818181146012578301005b601b6001356025565b8060005260206000f25b600060078202905091905056"
```